# Issue with large image performance in Flash (AIR app)

Tags: performance, image, air

I think my issue may be with using large images. Let me describes what happens.

The way that I load these images is by having all instances of my class DynamicImage on frame 2 in the timeline. It loads an image based on an XML that has been read in before.

```
public class DynamicImage extends DynamicSingleImage
{

    //var eLoader:Loader; //for english image
    var aLoader:Loader; //for alternate language image
    public function DynamicImage()
    {
        //loadMyImage(); //don't need to do this...super does this
        ...         
    }

    override public function loadMyImage () :void 
    {
        ...
            }
```

It doesn't matter to me that when we get to frame 2...the app just loads the assets.

So just to make this question short...I have two DynamicImages that are loaded (they are 3840 x 2400). I have a toggle button that toggles between the two images. Let's call them A and B.

The behavior is as follows.
A is defaulted on.
When I first switch to B...there's a split second delay before B shows. Now when I toggle back and forth between A and B (changing their "visible" property)...it's pretty immediate. I then go on to use other parts of my app...which also has some large images that I'm toggling on/off(also using visible = false/true).  When I go back to A & B, when I toggle for the first time, I see that split second delay again!

Is it because flash is loading/unloading these images from memory? Should I try to get this AIR app to use more memory? What else could be happening here?

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with drawing the image in the display, the images you are working with are really quite big! can´t you reduce them? what are you trying to do? I wrote a small class to offset basic image transformations to SIPS (mac only) so you could load smaller proxy images. Since SIPS works with the GPU, it´s ultra fast!! I was working with 300mb+ images and it loaded almost instantly.

maybe it helps anybody: http://www.inklink.co.at/blog/?p=90